# How do I copy over an integer from kernel space using copy_to_user?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

#### Problem

I am unable to copy over the data.

---

#### User Space

Here is my user space:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<sys/sysinfo.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *mytask;
    short allsize;
    struct sysinfo si;
    struct passwd *passwdStruct;

    // to get the userid of my raspberry pi so i can see all of us processes

    const char * usrnm = argv[1];
    passwdStruct = getpwnam(usrnm);
    uid_t usrid = passwdStruct->pw_uid;

    // testing grabbing information 
    int holder = 7;
    void * ptr; // im making this a void pointer b/c copy_to_user takes a void * as parameter
    ptr = &holder;

    printf("old stuff: %d\n", holder);

    int sys_retval = syscall(398, usrid, allsize, ptr);

    printf("new stuff: \n");
    printf("p: %d\n", holder);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Kernel Space

Here is my kernel space:

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>
//#include<linux/pwd.h> // includes the passwd struct which has id
//#include<sys/types.h> 
#include "mycall.h"
#include <linux/unistd.h>



asmlinkage long sys_sayhello(uid_t myusername, int siz, void __user *ptr)
{
    uid_t myid = myusername;
    const void *kern; // 2nd argument for copy_to_user
    struct task_struct *mytask;

// collect all the necessary info into the kernel array 
    for_each_process(mytask)
    {
        if (myid == mytask->cred->uid.val) // if the process belongs to the pi user
        {
            kern = &(mytask->pid); // I looked up kernel documentation and 
            copy_to_user(ptr, kern, sizeof(int)); // looks like pid is an INT type
            return;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Output

The program prints out:

> "old stuff: 7
>   new stuff: 7"

---

#### Question

The number should have changed to the first `pid` of my `pi` process in the output. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe not directly relevant to your problem, but all the casting of pointers has no effect.  The kernel doesn't care what type the user program thought the pointer had; it only cares about the bits.  And why not just make everything `pid_t` instead of guessing about the size of `int`?

Comment: Maybe you ought to insert some printk to check whether your `if (myid == ...)` ever succeeds.  It could be that you never get to execute `copy_to_user` in the first place.  If you do, you may also wish to check the return value of `copy_to_user`.

Comment: Indeed, have you tried getting `copy_to_user` to work in a simpler case?  `int foo = 12345; if(copy_to_user(ptr, &foo, sizeof(int)) != 0) printk("fail\n");`

Comment: Finally, check the value of `sys_retval` and if necessary the value of `errno`.  If you get `ENOSYS`, your system call is not actually being called.